# Phonegap 2.6 with KeyboardShrinksView and HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar

Tags: ios, cordova

i have a problem with one of the new phonegap features in 2.6 (ios), finally they included an option to shrink the webview to handle fixed elements. Unfortunately in combination with the `HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar` option set to true, a strange white bar appears instead of the AccessoryView (take a look at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fgV8.png)).
This is not happening when i set `KeyboardShrinksView` to false

has anyone experienced a similar problem with the new version? is this a bug or a feature? ;)

cheers
horst.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug. It's caused by the WebView not being resized properly after the keyboard is displayed. By default, PhoneGap resizes the height of the WebView by subtracting the view frame by the height of the keyboard. But, it doesn't take into account the fact that the form accessory bar is hidden in that calculation.

Here's a temporary solution to this while PhoneGap fixes this bug:

In CDVViewController.m (under Classes/Cleaver), go to line 140. It should be within the (void) keyboardWilLShowOrHide function. In the showEvent if statement, it calculates the new size of the WebView based on the height of the keyboard.

Change the contents of the if statement to:

```
if (showEvent) {
    newFrame.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height;
    if ([@"true" isEqualToString: self.settings[@"HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar"]]) {
        newFrame.size.height += 45;
    }
}
```

I added an extra if statement that also checks for the HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar configuration. If it's set, it'll increase the size of the WebView by an additional 45 pixels (the height of the form accessory bar).

Answer (score 1):

While the keyboard is transitioning up, it seems the webview is already resized and the background is white, thus causing the white background to be shown.  My HTML body background is black so it looks odd when the white background flashes.  Does anyone know how to update the background of the UIView?

Video reproducing the issue in slow motion.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOjdxJuYp8c

Thanks!

Tom

Edit: I was able to change the background color by adding this code to MainViewConetroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.0 green:51/255.0 blue:51/255.0 alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: very cool!
since i have different background colors it's not the best solution but looks much better than that plain shadow-ish white.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a bug. The phonegap dev team is going to fix this issue in the 2.7 release in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked my code and I have 2.6 and this fix is already there. But it is not working and I still see the grey bar with the same conditions. How that could be?

EDIT: It looks like that one of my teammates did this fix and solved the issue. The thing is that you still can see the grey space and it is removed very quickly.