# PhoneGap 2.7 HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar Not Workig

Tags: cordova

In config.xml file I have added the line:

```
<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
```

To remove the bar on the keyboard in iOS but it does not work and the bar is still displayed.

I am working with HTML,CSS,javaScript and editor Notepad++.

I've seen talk about a CDVViewController but I do not know how to work with this.

I'm relatively new at PhoneGap.So glad if you help me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug.

1. Try to set property `KeyboardShrinksView = true` in `config.xml` using preference tag.

2.May be it's caused by the `WebView` not being resized properly after the keyboard is displayed. By default, `PhoneGap` resizes the height of the `WebView` by subtracting the view frame by the height of the keyboard. But, it doesn't take into account the fact that the form accessory bar is hidden in that calculation.

Here's a temporary solution to this while `PhoneGap` fixes this bug:

In `CDVViewController.m` (under Classes/Cleaver), go to line 140. It should be within the `- (void) keyboardWilLShowOrHide` method. In the `showEvent` if statement, it calculates the new size of the `WebView` based on the height of the keyboard.

Change the contents of the if statement to:

```
if (showEvent) {
    newFrame.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height;
    if ([@"true" isEqualToString: self.settings[@"HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar"]]) {
        newFrame.size.height += 45;
    }
}
```

I added an extra if statement that also checks for the `HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar` configuration. If it's set, it'll increase the size of the WebView by an additional 45 pixels (the height of the form accessory bar).

I have faced similar problem. This solution worked for me.Hope you will find your answer.

Comment: how do i import the file(CDVViewController.m)?

Comment: It would be courteous to mention that the answer is copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16356603/502381.